# Conclude $u$ cannot obtain its maximum if it fulfills a linear differential inequality $Lu \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a function $u \in C^2((a,b)) \cap C^0([a,b])$ and a bounded function $g : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, whereas $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$

Now consider the linear operator $L := \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + g\frac{d}{dx}$ . I would like to show that if $Lu \geq 0$ then either $u$ is constant or it cannot obtain its maximum in $(a,b)$.

I can show that if $Lu >0$ then $u$ cannot obtain its maximum, 
since if it did obtain a maximum in $(a,b)$ at, let's say $x_0$, then $Lu(x_0) = u''(x_0) + g(x_0)u'(x_0) \leq 0$ (using the fact that the second derivative at a maximum must be negative and that the first derivative must be zero)

I am not quite sure how to prove the case $Lu \geq 0$ and I am also quite uncertain where the boundedness of $g$ would come into play. Any hints are greatly apreciated.

Comment: This is called the (one-dimensional) **strong maximum principle**, a not so trivial result. For a proof, see, e.g., Theorem 1 on pp. 2-3 of Protter and Weinberger [Maximum Principles in Differential Equations](https://books.google.com/books/about/Maximum_Principles_in_Differential_Equat.html?id=OTO2gRi5hGEC&redir_esc=y).